# Can I use imgaeButton to upload image to firebase Storage

Tags: android

I tried to upload an image while using the imageView in android and it did successfully uploaded the image. But when I used imageButton in the place of imageView I get the error.

```
imageButton.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
imageButton.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = imageButton.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, boas);
imageButton.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
byte[] data = boas.toByteArray();

String path = "firememes/" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".png";
StorageReference firememRef = storage.getReference(path);
```

I am getting this error

```
07-19 17:17:17.154 21469-21469/com.umer.listview D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-19 17:17:17.154 21469-21469/com.umer.listview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.umer.listview, PID: 21469
                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                                                                       at com.umer.listview.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:125)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I am getting error at this line of code bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, boas);

Comment: yes we know that. The error message says it

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're trying to set the image to a ***null object***,that mean that android can't find the object in this case your **ImageButton** where to set the image got from the **DB**, that means that you have to initialize the activity where you have your button **before** y*ou'll set the image to it from the firebase.*